# Adding new types to go-units

Tags: go

I wanted to use [NewRatioConversion](https://github.com/bcicen/go-units/blob/v1.0.5/conversion.go#L36) to add various measurements that could be beneficial and for which I already have the math, like teaspoons, tablespoons, drops, sprays, etc.

The 'how' seems pretty cut-and-dried, but the 'where' escapes me.  I'm pretty new to GoLang, but I figure I need to add in a go file which claims the 'units' package and adds them in.

I tried just adding them in the code I had, and I got a list of measurements which included teaspoon, but when I tried to use it it blew up.

I figure the method is going to be the same for any packages which allow for this kind of behavior, so any suggestions which seem remotely applicable will offer clues, I'm sure.

I tried putting the setup in one of the initial functions, which worked ok for returning the measurement but blew up when I tried to use it (before I tried, actually).  This just returns the list of measurements, and it includes 'tsp'.

```
func ValidVolumeUnits() []string {
    Teaspoon := units.NewUnit("Teaspoon(s)", "tsp")
    units.NewRatioConversion(Teaspoon, units.MilliLiter, 4.93)
    return []string{
        units.Liter.Symbol,
        units.MilliLiter.Symbol,
        units.Quart.Symbol,
        units.Pint.Symbol,
        units.Gallon.Symbol,
        units.FluidOunce.Symbol,
        Teaspoon.Symbol,
    }
}
```